# Call an API with HTTP request from SFMC Automation Studio

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketingcloudapi

I'd like to call an external API using HTTP Post method and store the response in Data Extension.

```
    <script runat="server">
    
    Platform.Load("core","1.1");
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init("LogDE");
    try 
    {
            var toDate = "2021-07-15T11:40:06";
            var fromDate = "2021-07-16T11:40:06";
            var payload = 
                {
                  dateFrom: fromDate,
                  dateTo: toDate
                }
            var url = 'apiURL_here';
            var contentType = 'application/json';
            var headerNames = ["contentType", "apikey"];
            var headerValues = ["application/json", "apikey_here"];
            var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, payload, headerNames, headerValues);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        logDE.Rows.Add({Message:error.message});
    }
</script>
```

It doesn't even go to the catch phase, it throws an error that I can't even debug in Automation Studio. Any hints? I removed the apikey and url obviously.
Kind regards, Jo

Comment: Your previous question - [Call external API from Salesforce Marketing Cloud and store in DE](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349721/call-external-api-from-salesforce-marketing-cloud-and-store-in-de) was closed due to being off-topic. By copying and pasting literally the same question again, will not help the situation. You can improve the question and it would improve chances to get an answer.

Comment: I've edited the question, the previous one didn't have any code part, whereas this has. I edited the old one, but it's in the closed pool in which I doubt somebody would answer me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the payload, adding Stringify helped, like so

```
<script runat="server">
    
    Platform.Load("core","1.1");
    var logDE = DataExtension.Init("LogDE");
    try 
    {
            var toDate = "2021-07-15T11:40:06";
            var fromDate = "2021-07-16T11:40:06";
            var payload = 
                {
                  dateFrom: fromDate,
                  dateTo: toDate
                }
            var url = 'apiURL_here';
            var contentType = 'application/json';
            var headerNames = ["contentType", "apikey"];
            var headerValues = ["application/json", "apikey_here"];
            var result = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload), headerNames, headerValues);
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        logDE.Rows.Add({Message:error.message});
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is better to troubleshoot your code in CloudPage, which is able to output the results rather than Automation Studio that will only throw a generic error.
To output errors add `Write(Stringify(error));`.

Considering that the error occurs before the try-catch block, then you can check:

1. If you are using an External Key of the Data Extension in  `DataExtension.Init("LogDE");` [function](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_dataExtensionFunctions.htm)
2. If you really have a field called "Message" in the "LogDE" Data Extension
3. There is also no closing tag `</script>` on the end.

Other than that, your code looks good, not considering your `HTTP.Post` part, since we do not have enough information about what you are doing there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The Data extension was fine and script code got lost somewhere when adding the code snippet here, but was there in the code. The issue was with payload, it has to be "stringified" if that's a word :)